# How to handle assignment and variable syntax in an interpreter

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar

Most interpreters let you type the following at their console:

```
>> a = 2
>> a+3
5
>>
```

My question is what mechanisms are usually used to handle this syntax? Somehow the parser is able to distinguish between an assignment and an expression even though they could both start with a digit or letter. It's only when we retrieve the second token that you know if you have an assignment or not. In the past, I've looked ahead two tokens and if the second token isn't an equals I push the tokens back into the lexical stream and assume it's an expression. I suppose one could treat the assignment as an expression which I think some languages do. I thought of using left-factoring but I can't see it working.

eg

```
assignment = variable A
A = '=' expression | empty
```

**Update** I found this question on StackOverflow which address the same question: [How to modify parsing grammar to allow assignment and non-assignment statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40777094/how-to-modify-parsing-grammar-to-allow-assignment-and-non-assignment-statements/40791485#40791485)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From how you're describing your approach - doing a few tokens of lookahead to decide how to handle things - it sounds like you're trying to write some sort of top-down parser along the lines of an LL(1) or an LL(2) parser, and you're trying to immediately decide whether the expression you're parsing is a variable assignment or an arithmetical expression. There are several ways that you could parse expressions like these quite naturally, and they essentially involve weakening one of those two assumptions.

The first way we could do this would be to switch from using a top-down parser like an LL(1) or LL(2) parser to something else like an LR(0) or SLR(1) parser. Those parsers work bottom-up by reading larger prefixes of the input string before deciding what they're looking at. In your case, a bottom-up parser might work by seeing the variable and thinking "okay, I'm either going to be reading an expression to print or an assignment statement, but with what I've seen so far I can't commit to either," then scanning more tokens to see what comes next. If they see an equals sign, great! It's an assignment statement. If they see something else, great! It's not. The nice part about this is that if you're using a standard bottom-up parsing algorithm like LR(0), SLR(1), LALR(1), or LR(1), you should probably find that the parser generally handles these sorts of issues quite well and no special-casing logic is necessary.

The other option would be to parse the entire expression assuming that = is a legitimate binary operator like any other operation, and then check afterwards whether what you parsed is a legal assignment statement or not. For example, if you use Dijkstra's shunting-yard algorithm to do the parsing, you can recover a parse tree for the overall expression, regardless of whether it's an arithmetical expression or an assignment. You could then walk the parse tree to ask questions like

- if the top-level operation is an assignment, is the left-hand side a single variable?
- if the top-level operation isn't an assignment, are there nested assignment statements buried in here that we need to get rid of?

In other words, you'd parse a broader class of statements than just the ones that are legal, and then do a postprocessing step to toss out anything that isn't valid.

Comment: I am indeed writing a parser, more as an exercise to better understand the theory. I want to stick for now with LL(k) type parsers because that's what I want to learn. I've used tools like yacc (LALR ) in the past but wanted to write something by hand. I think you answer my question though, either use a different parsing system that is more flexible or stick with LL() and treat equals as a legitimate operator.